# Last expected calculation doesn't match tester. Could my setDimensions method be whats wrong?

Tags: java, class, methods

for my coding class we are creating a class that calculates the cost of a window's glaze for our window company. When grading my code with the tester it seems that my method to change the dimensions of the window doesnt work. Here is the constructor of the window:

```
public Window(double width, double height) {
    double rectangleArea = width*height;
    double radius = width/2;
    double circleArea= Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 2);
    double semiCircleArea= circleArea/2;
    double areaFeetSquared= rectangleArea + semiCircleArea;
    area= areaFeetSquared*SQUARE_INCHES_PER_SQUARE_FOOT;
    double amountOfGlaze= area/SQUARE_INCHES_PER_OUNCE_OF_GLAZE;
    costOfGlaze= amountOfGlaze*COST_PER_OUNCE;
}
```

And here is my setDimensions method that isn't working

```
public void setDimensions(double theWidth, double theHeight) {
    width= theWidth;
    height= theHeight;
}
```

If you need more context, I would be more than happy to provide some more when asked. Thank you for reading, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you show the attributes of your class?

Comment: It looks like you only change the width and the height, but forget to recalculate the area like you do in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Besides updating the width and height, you also need to recalculate the area like you do in the constructor.

```
public Window(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    calculateArea();
}

private void calculateArea() {
    double rectangleArea = width * height;
    double radius = width / 2;
    double circleArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    double semiCircleArea = circleArea / 2;
    double areaFeetSquared = rectangleArea + semiCircleArea;
    area = areaFeetSquared * SQUARE_INCHES_PER_SQUARE_FOOT;
    double amountOfGlaze = area / SQUARE_INCHES_PER_OUNCE_OF_GLAZE;
    costOfGlaze = amountOfGlaze * COST_PER_OUNCE;
}

public void setDimensions(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    calculateArea();
}
```

Comment: It might still be useful to store `width` and `height` in the object.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to recalculate your properties after updating `width` and `height`. You can do so by calling a method which basically just executes the code inside your constructor again.

```
public void setDimensions(double theWidth, double theHeight)
{
    width= theWidth;
    height= theHeight;
    recalculate();
}
```

And the `recalculate()` method could look like this:

```
private void recalculate()
{
    double rectangleArea = width*height;
    double radius = width/2;
    double circleArea= Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 2);
    double semiCircleArea= circleArea/2;
    double areaFeetSquared= rectangleArea + semiCircleArea;
    area= areaFeetSquared*SQUARE_INCHES_PER_SQUARE_FOOT;
    double amountOfGlaze= area/SQUARE_INCHES_PER_OUNCE_OF_GLAZE;
    costOfGlaze= amountOfGlaze*COST_PER_OUNCE;
}
```

This would update your properties after changing `width` and `height`.